Creating a jks with a pem file that only has private key
I have a pem file that only contains a private key, e.g.:
-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
XXXXXXX
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----

I need to convert this into a JKS keystore and I have tried:
keytool -import -keystore test.jks -file private-key.pem

but I get the error message: "keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Input not an X.509 certificate
"
how can I go about doing this, do I need to provide a dummy certificate?

Yes, you must provide a certificate containing the public key corresponding to the private key you are trying to import.
